# How can I delete this Laravel form using get method

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, forms

The 'Delete' method was not working so I used 'get' but my data is not deleting

```html
<form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{ url('/data', $row['id']) }}" id="studentForm_{{$row['id']}}">
  {{ method_field('GET') }}
  {{  csrf_field() }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">{{ trans('Delete') }}</button>
</form>
```

```php
  public function destroy($id)
  {
    dd($id);
    $student = Student::where('id',$id)->delete();
    return redirect('/data/{id}')->with('success', 'Data Deleted');
  }
}

Route::get('/data/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@index');
Route::delete('/data/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@destroy');
```

Comment: Your form is sending a POST request, not a GET

Comment: u r seinding via POST see `method="post"`, also after delete you cant redirect on deleted id

Comment: Never use GET for deletion. Bots can visit GET and then you can lose data.

Comment: You also should remove `dd($id);` since that exits your script, code after it will not be executed

Comment: Please clarify what **exactly** you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

This is I finally got the answer
I ran the following command:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:list
```

Then it gave me suggested methods and delete method was shown for "Controller@destroy" route then I changed from "get" method to "delete" method. Then, my post was able to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The form must be submitted via delete method

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/data', $row['id']) }}"> 
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">{{ trans('Delete') }}</button>
</form>
```

More details can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: But I use delete method it would throw an error, Get method is working but the issue is that the posts refuses to delete and no error is shown so please I would love to get another suitable answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am thinking the issue here is not the method it should be from the route hmmm I don't think the controller has any issue but you could check if there is then lets know the way forward.

Comment: can you try dd($student) to see what is output?

Comment: you can try if($student) then redirect